# How to find elements in a 2x2 matrix when given the determinant, a, and b

Tags: math, matrix, determinants

So I am given the determinant for a 2 by 2 matrix, I am also given the values for a and b as a vector which is the first row of the matrix. I can't figure out how I would find c and d

determinant of matrix C is equal to +-1, the vector of [1,2] is [a,b], please find c and d to complete the equation ac - bd = +-1

Comment: The determinant of a (general) 2x2 matrix (a b \\ c d) is given by ad-bc and not ac-bd. You're trying to solve the equation det (1 2 \\ c d) = ±1 which breaks down to d-2c=±1, which means there are infinite solutions to this problem.

Comment: As @alexschu98 says, there are infinite solutions. However, assuming the row `[d, c]` are also integer values, you can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find 'parametric' expressions for the (infinite) solution pairs for: `[d, c]`. Note however, that there are, in general, only *two* `[d, c]` pairs such that `|d| + |c|` is minimised.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments of @alexchu98 and @BrettHale , here is a solution using sympy

```py
from sympy import *
a,b,c,d = symbols('a b c d', integer=True)
A = Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])

def solve_val(val):
    D = A.det()
    eq = Eq(D,val)
    display(eq)
    eq1 = eq.subs({a:1,b:2})
    display(eq1)
    from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import diop_solve
    sol = diop_solve(eq1.lhs - eq1.rhs)
    display(sol)
    print("===")

solve_val(1)
solve_val(-1)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]